# USe data from another object VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have quick question here.

I have my object with value:

```
  data() {
    return {
      nation: {
        CZ: require("../../../../../svg/czech-flag.svg"),
      }
    };
  },
```

Then have API object (API is working fine, fyi)

```
  doctor: {
    region: "CZ"
  }
```

I wanna do something like this (is not working of course):

```
<div v-html="nation.doctor.region></div>
```

I had method for this, it worked, but I think it can be easier to do that. Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Instead of all the ```../../../``` you can use ```@/``` to get to the ```src/``` directory. Your code will become much more clear.

Comment: Thank you for advice - in this project is still, i dont know why, not exist vue config file, so its not working yet. But I will use it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `` nations[`${doctor.region}`] ``

Working code:

```js
const data = {
    nations: {
        CZ: 'Czech'
    }
}

const doctor = {
    region: 'CZ'
}

console.log(data.nations[`${doctor.region}`])
```